# Testing fails to import sub dependency - @testable import SubModule - Use of undeclared type 'InternalSubModuleType'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, testability

I have a unit test that needs to access internal methods/properties on a module imported by my application target.

E.g.

SubModule.swift

```
public class SubModuleType {
    ...
    internal let value: InternalSubModuleType
    ...
}
```

AppViewController.swift

```
import SubModule
// do things with SubModuleType
```

AppViewControllerTests.swift

```
@testable import App
@testable import SubModule

func testWithSubModule() {
    let internalSubModuleTypeInstance = SubModule.SubModuleType().value
    // ... run a test dependent on internalSubModuleTypeInstance
}
```

In this test I receive 'Use of undeclared type 'InternalSubModuleType'' when accessing `.value`.

- I have added the `SubModule` target to `App-Tests` "Target Dependencies"
- I have set "Enable Testability" to YES for both the App target and SubModule target for the scheme I'm compiling for testing.

`@testable import` is supposed to allow you to access types marked internal under these conditions. I'm not sure why I'd be receiving this compiler error. I can still use *any* type that is marked internal in my App target by using `@testable` but not my SubModule target.

Are you only allowed 1 target to be `@testable import` in a test target or is there something I'm missing?

---

using Xcode 9, Swift 3.2

Comment: I'm seeing something similar (not exactly the same)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600071/xcode-9-not-linking-indexing-correctly

Have you tried something to force an index to happen and see if resolves it by any chance?  This isn't an answer, just seeing if there's a relationship.

Comment: I've tried quitting Xcode, deleting derived data, reopening and recompiling numerous times and it doesn't work. When I delete derived data it reindexes. This does look very similar however, wonder if it's a bug in Xcode 9. This setup on this project is new though (post Xcode 9 release) so I have nothing to compare against.

Comment: I have tried the following which has improved it.  I suspect part of the problem, for me, is that Xcode works in a manner different to what I think it should in my head.
- Make changes in App Target
- Save each source file as I go along - CMD-S
- Build app
- Switch to Unit Test Target
- Make changes, saving files as I go along.  This seems to pick up app changes but not always straightaway.  It could be indexing slowly in the background (very slowly, it's a tiny app!)
- Build - this seems to tidy up any lingering error messages
- Run tests
As you say, I suspect the issue is different.

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the Testing target seemed to have done the trick for me.

Simply delete your old Testing target, create a new one and add this target to all the testing files that you have.